# php db2_connect - what driver is being used?

Tags: php, database, apache, connection, db2

```
    $connection = db2_connect ( '*LOCAL', PHP_USER_NAME, PHP_USER_PASS );
    if (! $connection) {
        die('Could not connect');
    }

    //Prepare and execute the SQL statement.
    $stmt = db2_prepare ( $connection, $sqlStatement );

    if (! db2_execute ( $stmt ) ) {
        Throw New Exception('Could not execute statement');
    }
```

We are running PHP on an IBM iSeries with Apache.  Our database is also on this iSeries.

What sort of connection is being established?  Is it an ODBC link?  If this is something that varies from system to system, how can i tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that is is a `ODBC` connection:

Try running the function [`db2_client_info`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-client-info.php) on your client, this should output the needed info. You can run the following code:

```
<?php
$conn = db2_connect( '*LOCAL', PHP_USER_NAME, PHP_USER_PASS );
$client = db2_client_info( $conn );

if ($client) {
    echo "DRIVER_NAME: ";           var_dump( $client->DRIVER_NAME );
    echo "DRIVER_VER: ";            var_dump( $client->DRIVER_VER );
    echo "DATA_SOURCE_NAME: ";      var_dump( $client->DATA_SOURCE_NAME );
    echo "DRIVER_ODBC_VER: ";       var_dump( $client->DRIVER_ODBC_VER );
    echo "ODBC_VER: ";              var_dump( $client->ODBC_VER );
    echo "ODBC_SQL_CONFORMANCE: ";  var_dump( $client->ODBC_SQL_CONFORMANCE );
    echo "APPL_CODEPAGE: ";         var_dump( $client->APPL_CODEPAGE );
    echo "CONN_CODEPAGE: ";         var_dump( $client->CONN_CODEPAGE );
}
else {
    echo "Error retrieving client information.
     Perhaps your database connection was invalid.";
}
db2_close($conn);

?>
```